# Java: regex - groups in general

Tags: java, regex

Lets say i have some regex = "..(group1)..|..(group2).."

```
pattern.matcher(regex)
matcher.find()
// how can i access the result?? 
// i dont wanna use matcher.group(1) or matcher.group(2) 
// since i don't really know what will be the result.
```

As u can see i don't know how to get my result. im looking for something like matcher.getResultedGroup.. Could anyone please explain what should i do?

- If u have other suggestion to expand my knowledge i'd love to hear..

Comment: Hi Popokoko, is there a reason why this question has no accepted answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single capturing group, with non capturing groups inside:

```
((?:group1)|(?:group2))
```

Comment: There is no need to put parantheses around the complete regexp, the actual match of the full regexp is in group 0.

Comment: Yes, this example is meaningful as part of a larger expression.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over [`Matcher.start(groupNum)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start%28int%29). `groupNum` that is not `0`, but starts at `0` is what you are looking for (assuming that it's your whole expression).

Otherwise include your whole subexpression into a capturing group: `((group1)|(group2)...)` and compare the starting indexes of the inner groups to the outer group.

Comment: This is what ive been doing.. though it looks pretty wired it does work (but not perfect..) for (int m = 1; m <= matcher.groupCount(); m++) {
    if (matcher.group(m) != null) {
     r = matcher.group(m);
    }
   }

Answer (score 0):

See the Javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Maybe somthing like this will work:

```
while(matcher.find()) {
    String groupMatch = matcher.group(groupIndex)
}
```

matcher.find will try to find all subsequences (substrings) of a string which are matched by your regular expression.

Comment: i should have mention im pretty new with regex and it takes a while to understand everything

Comment: See my updated comment and the others as well, each of them are good on their own :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go into subgroups if you don't want to. The actual match is in group 0: `Matcher.group(0)` or the equivalent `Matcher.group()`. Note that you might want to use non-capturing groups to safe resources.